# Why some features are overriden after installation

Tags: 7, features, installation

This is my hook_install:

```
function moocollar_web_install() {

  // enable features
  $global_features = array ('display_modes_feature' , 'field_bases_feature' , 'image_styles_feature' , 'roles_permissions_feature' , 'sitewide_feature'  , 'wysiwyg_feature' , 'menus_feature');
  $functionality_features = array ('blog_feature');

  $enable_dependencies = TRUE;
  module_enable($global_features, $enable_dependencies);
  module_enable($functionality_features, $enable_dependencies);

  // create editor user
  $role = user_role_load_by_name ('editor');
  $new_user = new stdClass();
  $new_user->name = 'editor';
  $new_user->pass = user_password(8); // random password.
  $new_user->mail = 'editor@example.com';
  if ($role) {
    $new_user->roles = array ($role->rid => $role->name);
  } 
  $new_user->status = 1;
  $new_user->is_new = TRUE;
  user_save($new_user);

  variable_set('features_default_export_path', 'profiles/moocollar_web/modules/features');
}
```

After install the blog_feature is overriden:

```
drush features-diff blog_feature
Legend: 
Code:       drush features-revert will remove the overrides.
Overrides:  drush features-update will update the exported feature with the displayed overrides


Component type: info
  features[field_instance][] = node-blog_post-body
  features[field_instance][] = node-blog_post-field_image
< features[menu_links][] = menu-editor-menu_aadir-post:node/add/blog-post
  features[node][] = blog_post
  features[user_permission][] = create blog_post content


Component type: menu_links
< array(
<   'menu-editor-menu_aadir-post:node/add/blog-post' => array(
<     'customized' => 1,
<     'link_path' => 'node/add/blog-post',
<     'link_title' => 'Añadir post',
<     'menu_name' => 'menu-editor-menu',
<     'module' => 'menu',
<     'options' => array(
<       'identifier' => 'menu-editor-menu_aadir-post:node/add/blog-post',
<     ),
<     'router_path' => 'node/add/blog-post',
<   ),
< )
---
> array()
```

But if I execute revert features via drush, the features is on default state:

```
drush features-revert blog_feature
Do you really want to revert blog_feature.menu_links? (y/n): y
Reverted blog_feature.menu_links.                                                                       [ok]
vagrant@precise32 (linkinicio *) httpdocs$ drush fd blog_feature
Feature is in its default state. No diff needed.
```

On the blog_feature.info I've the dependency and the item:

```
...
dependencies[] = menu
dependencies[] = menus_feature
....
features[menu_links][] = menu-editor-menu_aadir-post:node/add/blog-post
....
```

Thanks you all for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally Features automatically detects ctools exportables and add the modules containing those exportables to the dependency list, unless a module requirement for an exportable was not detected, or dependent modules were installed since feature was enabled.

Based on your menu link machine name (`menu-editor-...`), it seems it relies on [Menu Editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_editor) module and you've missing dependency to that module, therefore Features module didn't detect that component as a requirement, so it become overridden and unrevertable.

The solution is to add the missing module into `dependencies` list. Then either disable the feature module and reenable it, or manually enable any dependencies not enabled (see Feature Diff to expose them).

See: [Troubleshooting: Reasons Features may be stuck as Overridden](https://www.drupal.org/node/986932) at Drupal.org